# Rewrite request on Nginx from GET to POST with body (for tracking pixel)

Tags: web-services, redirect, nginx, webserver, tracking-pixel

I'm trying to figure out if there's an easy way to convert a tracking pixel request that gets to Nginx into a POST that will go to an upstream with some added body.

for exmaple, if I get a GET request for `http://domain.com/track/mail-id.gif`, I'd like to configure Nginx to convert it to a POST that goes to `http://upstream/mail-id` with some body (let's say status:opened).

how can it be done?

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to add a more detailed example:

```
location /track/mail-id.gif {
    proxy_pass http://upstream/mail-id;
    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_set_body "status:opened";
    # if needed
    # proxy_set_header Some-Header value;
}
```

Provided a url for `proxy_pass` here, so to ensure the exact behaviour requested.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Nginx proxy functionality to achieve this, specifically with the `proxy_method` directive.

Something like:

```
location /track/mail-id.gif {
    proxy_pass http://upstream
    proxy_method POST
}
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html for more information about Nginx proxy directives.